# Beginner jQuery Questions (FF/IE issue)

Tags: jquery, firefox

I've been playing around a bit, with jQuery, just trying to do some replacing of text fields on click of a link and hiding/showing of content items as well. It seems to be working just fine in IE, but I can't seem to get it to work in FF.

My jQuery:

```
$(function() {

$(".articles a").click(function() {
    articlenumber = "1"
    $(articlenumber).css("display", "none");
    articlenumber = $(this).attr("id");
    articlename = $(this).attr("name");
    articlenumber = '".' + articlenumber + '"';
    //alert(articlenumber);
    //$(articlenumber).css("display", "inline");
    $(articlenumber).attr("style", "display:inline;")
    $(".articletitle").text(articlename)
});
```

And my HTML for this(simplified):

```
<a id="article1" name="Article Title1" href="#">Link</a>
<a id="article2" name="Article Title2" href="#">Link</a>
<div class="articlename">Title</div>
<div class="article1" style="display:none;">Text 1</div>
<div class="article2" style="display:none;">Text 2</div>
```

Any suggestions as to why this isn't working in FireFox? And anything I can clean up here?

Comment: Adding var to the beginning didn't seem to change anything in FF, IE still works fine. And in this case I was just declaring it, but I need those values to be strings.

Comment: You've used the same `id` multiple times. The `id` attribute is meant to be unique. Also, it appears that you're using `articlenumber` as a selector, which is odd, since this will select the non-existent `1` element.

Comment: You're using firebug right?  http://getfirebug.com/

Comment: @Frank, you think? Look at this question =) But he certainly **should** be... =D

Comment: Just to be clear, it looks like you forgot to close the main function.

Answer (score 4):

```
$(".articles a").click(function() {
    articlenumber = "1"
    $(articlenumber).css("display", "none");
    articlenumber = $(this).attr("id");
    articlename = $(this).attr("name");
    articlenumber = '".' + articlenumber + '"';
    $(articlenumber).attr("style", "display:inline;")
    $(".articletitle").text(articlename)
});
```

Okay, in order of your script:

Declare your variables before you try to assign values, terminate the line and remember that 1 is numeric not a string:

```
articlenumber = "1"
```

should be

```
var articlenumber = 1;
```

jQuery typically expects the identifier to be an `id`, a `class` or an element-type (`a`, `li` etc). Neither an `id` nor a `class` can start with a number, they have to start with either and underscore `_` or a letter (plus a couple other characters I can't remember), and there are no elements `<1>`. This could be a problem since with:

```
$(articlenumber)
```

is equivalent to either:

```
$(1) or $('1')
```

both of which are, or should be, invalid (I think).

Then you're reassigning `articlenumber` again *without* first declaring it a `var` (the same is true in the following line when you initialise `articlename`.

---

I'm not sure if these are your main problems (I removed your commented-out code), but fix the obvious, then we can talk more.

I would suggest, strongly, that you get hold of Firebug and watch its console as you load/interact with the page in Firefox. It'll tell you the main problems you're having. Also, as an addenda, I'd strongly suggest that you develop your sites/scripts with either Google Chrome (with the Web Inspector), Safari Webkit (as with Chrome), Mozilla Firefox (with Firebug, as above) and/or Opera (with Dragonfly). These browsers and web-development tools will more or less force you to develop your scripts properly. Once they're working, and valid, *then* try it in IE.

More often than not it'll work there if it works everywhere else, developing in IE *first* seems to allow you to develop bad habits, and error-prone JavaScript/jQuery, and then become confused, flustered or frustrated when the other browsers refuse to play ball.

Comment: Good advice, thank you David - I will try this now and get back to you. I appreciate the information. -Scott

Comment: No worries, 's always a pleasure =)

Answer (score 0):

Try changing this line:

```
$(".articletitle").text(articlename)
```

To

```
$(".articletitle").html(articlename)
```

Also I'm wondering if the class descriptors (.articletitle and .articlename) are correct? .articletitle class I do not see in the HTML - only in the javascript.. unless that's somewhere else.